# How can I incorporate an applescript function into Xcode?

Tags: macos, applescript, xcode

So I have a Cocoa-Applescript project, and I am creating an application:
[image: The window]

I have this script in applescript, it's in automator.

```
set input01 to (input as text)
```

The rest is kinda secret, but I'll show you one line :)

```
if "Hi" is input01 then say "Hello"
```

I need to take the text box in the window, and use the button to set the text in the box as input01 and initiate the script. Then, on the box on the right I would like a log of the output, 
e.g. what's being said by the computer. Is this possible? If not I can use automator, but I thought it was more customizable (the window's appearance) if I used XCODE. Thanks and have a nice day. Don't be afraid to ask for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

First: Why not just code the whole thing with Xcode in the app?
However you could print the text to a text file and then read it out in the applescript

Comment: The applescript takes long enough, I thought that that would make it take way longer and also provide unneeded files.I don't really know Objective C, so I was using Applescript because I found out how to do what I wanted.